# I cannot access cookie values in all php pages

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have a login page done in php and in that i am storing the username in cookie. But i cannot access this cookie variable in my home page which is also done in php, on thing i am doing all this in my localhost wamp server someone please help me to dothis

**login.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="login.css"/>
        <title> LOGIN Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id ="fullscreen">
        <div id="container">
        <div id="heading">LOGIN</div>
        <div id="login-form" >
                <form  id="my-login"  action="" method="POST">
                <input type ="text" name ="user_name" placeholder="  Enter login id" class="text_box" id="usrname">
                <label id ="lusr_name" value="" name="lusr_name"></label><br>
                <input type ="password" name ="password" placeholder="  Password" class="text_box" id="paswd">
                <label id ="lpassword" value="" name="password" ></label><br>
                <input type ="submit" name ="login" value ="Log In" class="login_button" >
                </form>
        </div>
        <a href="signup.php" id="my_signup">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php

        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            $username = $_POST['user_name'];
            $pwd = $_POST['password'];

        if(empty($username) || empty($pwd))
            {
            if(empty($username))
            {
                echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"lusr_name\").innerText=\"Enter username\";</script>";
                echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"usrname\").className=\"text_errorbox\";</script>";
            }
            if(empty($pwd))
            {
                echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"lpassword\").innerText=\"Enter Password\";</script>";
                echo "<script>document.getElementById(\"paswd\").className=\"text_errorbox\";</script>";
            }
            }
        else
        {
        //setcookie( "TestCookie",$username,false,"/",false ); 
                setcookie( 'TestCookie', $username, time()+60*60*24*7, '/', 'localhost', false, true);

        include 'userdata.php';
        $obj = new userdata();
        $obj -> authent($username,$pwd);
        }
        }
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

**homepage.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login Successful</title>
        <>
    </head>
    <body style="background:#323B55">
        <h1 style="text-align:center ;color:#ffffff;font-family:arial;">LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!!!!!!!!!</h1>
        <?php
            if(isset($_COOKIE['TestCookie']))
            {
            echo 'Welcome ' . $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to reload page to get cookie value

Comment: actually i am redirecting to the homepage so its always reloding while login

Answer (score 1):

I think when setting your cookie, you should remove 'localhost' as cookie Domain. Just leave it empty. `''`

**EDIT:**

Uhm, wait... `setCookie()` must be executed before ANY OTHER output has started! In your case you are outputting a lot of HTML before you do setCookie! Please execute the setCookie part first, or read up on [Output Buffering](http://php.net/ob_start).

Using setCookie after having started output should produce a notice/warning. But it could be that it has been suppressed.

Comment: but how do i save username before the html tags?

Comment: @DmitriMendeleev If you really don't know how to re-arrange your code to execute setCookie before you do any output, then just put `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the top of your file , and `<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>` at the bottom of your file. (Assuming you don't use `die();` or `exit();` in your code that would prevent you from reaching the bottom of your file.)

Comment: still it remains same !!

Answer (score 0):

Try using ths:-

This is an working example

```
$value="bikash";
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600);  
echo $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php ob_start(); ?> <html>
<head>
    <title>Login Successful</title>
    <>
</head>
<body style="background:#323B55">
    <h1 style="text-align:center ;color:#ffffff;font-family:arial;">LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!!!!!!!!!</h1>
    <?php
        if(isset($_COOKIE['TestCookie']))
        {
        echo 'Welcome ' . $_COOKIE['TestCookie'];
        }
    ?>
</body></html> <?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

try this code